# Не получается скомпилировать .cpp файл из командной строки

Tags: c++, windows-10, mingw, командная-строка

Установил самый последний *Code::Blocks с MinGW на Windows 10*.

Также прописал путь в Path системы `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin`.
Все как положено.

Затем создаю текстовый файл prog1.cpp с

`int main(){return 0;}`

(C:\Users\savva\Documents\CppLearning\prog1.cpp)

Затем иду в командную строку, там пишу:

```
cd C:\Users\savva\Documents\CppLearning

g++ -o prog1 prog1.cpp
```

И в итоге моментально вылетает эта ошибка и ничего не компилируется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из Code::Blocks все компилирует идеально.

Как чинить?

Comment: может ребутнуть машину?

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает.

Comment: А из под CodeBlock компилирует?

Comment: Да, компилирует. Забыл добавить в вопрос...

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте переустановил компилятор (и так версия старая, обновить не помешает), и сразу взял MinGW-w64 вместо обычного MinGW.

Comment: @Astralpirate возможно, у Вас установленно несколько версий  mingw и они "неаккуратно прописаны в PATH". и as.exe находит dl от другой версии

Comment: @HolyBlackCat установил отдельно MinGW-w64 и отдельно Code::Blocks, теперь все работает. Спасибо!